# Regular sequence from prime ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $I$ be a prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}_0$ (the localization at the maximal ideal that defines $0$) and suppose that the height of $I$ is $h$. Then, there is a standard *trick* to extract a regular sequence of length $h$ from $I$. And so one can always see $V:=V(I)$ (which has codimension $h$) as an irreducible component of a complete intersection of codimension $h$.

> Can you choose the regular sequence $g_1, \ldots, g_h$ so that the intersection of $V$ with each of the other irreducible components of $V(g_1,\ldots,g_h)$ is just $\{0\}$? What if we assume that the local ring of $(V(I),0)$ is Cohen-Macaulay?

It seems to me that this is a strong condition on the ideal $g:=(g_1, \ldots, g_h)$, however, you have some freedom to choose the elements within $I$. Observe, that this would imply that there exists a primary decomposition of $g$ such that the sum of the primary ideal corresponding to $V$ and any other primary ideal contains (a power of) the maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}_0$.

Comment: Last sentence, you meant: contains a power of the maximal ideal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is impossible to do this if $\dim V(I)\geq 2$. Because then $g$ defines a complete intersection of dimension at least $2$. But for any Cohen-Macaulay local ring of dimension at least $2$, the punctured spectrum is connected. (Unless of course if $V(g)$ has only one component, whence $I$ is a set-theoretic complete intersection).

Comment: I don't see why $\dim(V(I)) \geq 2$ implies that $g$ defines a complete intersection. This happens if the singular locus of $V(g)$ has codimension >1 by Hartshorne irreducibilty criterion, right? But the other irreducible components of $V(g)$ might intersect in codim 1 analytic sets.

Comment: You wrote that $g_1,...,g_h$ is a regular sequence.

Comment: I don't understand why this does not allow that the other irreducible components don't intersect in codim 1 sets. But on the other hand, your answer suggests that they have to intersect to $V(I)$ in something of codim > 2. Does this imply that $V(I)$ is neccesarily an embedded component in some other irreducible component? That $g_1, \ldots, g_h$ is a regular sequence just tells that $g_{i+1}$ does not vanish along a whole component of $V(g_1, \ldots, g_{i})$ but it may vanish along a part of $V(g_1, \ldots, g_{i})$.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. The height of $I$ is $h$, so it is not an embedded component.

Comment: Right. I didn't see that assuming that $g_1, \ldots, g_h$ was a regular sequence was playing against me, rather than with me. Do you know if it is possible if we don't require $g_1, \ldots, g_h$ to be a regular sequence? or if we don't assume that we are in a cohen-macaulay ring?

Comment: Paul, if depends on specifics. Of course, if you don't require anything from the $g$s, then we can just take them to be generators of $I$. My answer actually  says that as long as the quotient by the ideal $g$ has depth at least $2$, what you required forces $V(g) =V(I)$.

Comment: I just require that there are exactly h of them and the condition on V(I) intersecting only at 0 the other irreducible components.

Comment: Also, I would be happy with a nice reference (because, you know, each one is supposed to do their own research). I’m trying to follow pfister and de jong. But these seem more specific questions than the usual material covered in a textbook. I’m sorry if it feels that I asked without enough insight on the topic.